# Oracle Responsys Syntax for date calculation

Tags: sql, oracle, responsys

I have a hard time working with Oracle Responsys, Im trying to put a condition of less than 3 years from today-workdate, I have a timestamp called workdate

```
select * from $A$ where (to_char(workdate,'dd-mm-yy')-to_char(sysdate,'dd-mm-yy'))/365.242199<=3
```

Responsys doesn't like it, so I check the functions within Responsys and changed my sql code to :

```
select * from $A$ where $subtract_dates(workdate,now())$/365.242199<=3
```

Responsys still doesn't take it.

Responsys is not 100% oracle syntax. What's the right way to do it??
Thanks so much for whoever can help with this.

FYI The error msg is sql command not properly end.

Comment: calculate 3 years from today: `sysdate + interval '3' year`

Comment: is this responsys syntax? also that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: It's valid SQL (Oracle) syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right answer

```
select * from $A$ where workdate <= add_months(current_timestamp,-36)
```